# ex equivalent of d/^Mark for use with gvim -c and argdo

Tags: vim

I spend most of my time on Windows 8 and use `gvim -c` as a sed replacement. I think I can get sed with Cygwin, but I hope that I can do this with `gvim -c`.

I have a directory of tab-delimited .txt files, and some have a header (as follows) that I want to remove.

```
Definition of the Ultimate Owner :                                                                                                                                                  
- minimum percentage that must characterize the path from a subject company up to its Ultimate owner : 25.01%                                                                                                                                                   
- At least one of its shareholders must be known and it cannot own more than 25.01%                                                                                                                                                 

Mark     Company name ...
```

To remove the header in a gvim session I would use `d/^Mark`, then `:wq`. But I have hundreds of these, so I would like to use `gvim -c` and `argdo`. I do this a lot with `s//`, say something like `gvim -c "argdo %s/foo/bar/ge | wq" *.tex`.

My first thought was `gvim -c "d/^Mark | wq" *.txt`, but this doesn't work because `/` isn't an ex command.

Is there an ex equivalent of `d/^Mark` that I can use with `gvim -c` and `argdo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `:d[elete]` command, prepended with a range:

```
:[fromline],[toline]d
```

Ranges are not limited to absolute line numbers: search can be used too:

```
:1,/bar/d
```

deletes all the lines between line 1 and the first line containing `bar`.

The following command deletes every line between line 1 and the line above the first line starting with `bar`:

```
:1,/^bar/-1d
```

Assuming you don't pass other commands before that could move the cursor, we can cut out a couple of characters:

- the current line is assumed if the first part of the range is missing, since we open a new buffer and we didn't move the cursor we can remove the `1`,
- the default offset for `-` is `1`, since that's the offset we use we can leave the last `1` out too. The command becomes:

  :,/^bar/-d

Built from the bricks above, the following command should work:

```
$ gvim -c "argdo ,/^Mark/-d | wq" *.txt
```

Comment: I found a problem. When `Mark` is in the first row, first column, this deletes the first row so that I lose the header. Is there a solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: My proposed solution works for the snippet in your question. If you want a more generic solution you'll need to write a function that checks for the line number of the first `^Mark` and acts accordingly.